# pdf problem Close option c# winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created a PDF file,and  sent by mail, now I send one more time I'm getting this error

**The process.....because it is beingused by another process**

```
       Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);  

 try 

 {  

     PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("c:\\Test11.pdf",FileMode.Create));  

     doc.Open;  

      Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("This is my first line using Paragraph.");  

     Phrase pharse = new Phrase("This is my second line using Pharse.");  

     Chunk chunk = new Chunk(" This is my third line using Chunk.");  
  doc.Add(paragraph);  

     doc.Add(pharse);  
     doc.Add(chunk);  

 }  

catch (DocumentException dex)  

{  

 }  

 finally 

 {  
     doc.Close(); 
 }
```

Comment: Can you paste your code? How did you crate pdf file?

Comment: with itextSharp dll my question is how do I close this file ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the Document class closes the below streams opened in it as well?
Looks like it isnt. And to send as an attachment, first finish writing the pdf file to disk. Close it and then use FileMode.Open and FileShare.Read argument to read and send it. That way, multiple files can read it and send it or even in threads its possible.

Comment: Closed, now I can read and join, please if possible an example?

Comment: new FileStream("File", FileMode.Open, FileShare.Read"); api should work for your needs. Play with filestream classes. Look for its examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the physical PDF file on one application at a time.

Adding it as an attachement and sending it might keep the file open for a while. Copy the file before you do anything with it and simply 'send' or 'show' the copy.

File.Copy the original PDF file and send a copy

File.Copy the original PDF file and show the copy

This should prevent the 'file in use warnings'

Comment: I still can not send a second time   File.Copy(Application.StartupPath.ToString() + "\\hh.pdf", "fff.pdf", true);
                Attachment attachFile = new Attachment(Application.StartupPath.ToString() + "\\fff.pdf");

Comment: Copy to a new file every time HH1.pdf hh2.pdf hh3.pdf that hould do it. Maybe you need to close the writer using the wri.Close() or wri.Dispose() functions.